# socket not sending or receiving UDP

Tags: python, sockets

i have a weird situation here , i am trying to make a program that sends data and the other one receives the data . so the problem is i am sending the data and i am not receiving anything , so i don't know what is the problem here is the code for the sender :

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.sendto('hello'.encode(), ('192.168.100.42', 12500))
```

and the code for the receiver :

```
from socket import socket , SOCK_DGRAM, AF_INET
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(('192.168.100.42', 12500))
data, addr = sock.recvfrom(100)
print('a massage has been received !', addr, data)
```

i don't understand why it is not getting anything , and just to mention that i am sure that the IP is correct , i have opened the CMD and typed :

> ipconfig

anyway , thank you guys .

Comment: Replace the IP address with `0.0.0.0` and it will work.

Comment: no i tried it and it did not work .

Comment: Works for me with precisely the above, except for the IP, of course. What exactly happens? Does the sender process complete while the receiver hangs? What order do you start the processes in?

Comment: what do you mean by this : 'except for the IP ,' , this IP : 192.168.100.42 is my computer's IP and i am sure of it , so please explain what you have said .

Comment: i have tried TCP connection instead of the UDP and it worked correctly as i expected ! but still the UDP not working .. probably from the system .

Comment: The code as such should work, so I would suspect your system configuration. iptables or packet filter or what your OS uses. But I suspect if you tried (for instance with netcat) you would see not get through.

Comment: @hassan1551 I never doubted it to be your PC's IP. But it is not **my** PC's IP, so I naturally have to change it when I try to run your code on my PC, don't I?

Comment: @shmee really man ? you don't know this thing ??? yes you have to , because this is a private IP and it changes from a network to another .

Comment: Ever heard about the concept of rethorical questions? Yeah, I know this thing. The fact that I exchanged the IPs without your help could have told you that. Anyway, nice attitude. Maybe someone else will help you with your issue, I'm outta here ...